# Python loop over opened file

Tags: python, loops, file

I'm trying to count the amount of times (roughly) the word 'The' appears in a text.

```
book1 = 'imitation_of_christ.txt'
book2 = 'jesus_of_history.txt'

with open(book1, encoding='utf-8') as book1:
    lines = book1.readlines()
    word = 'the '
    times = lines.count(word)

    for line in lines:
        times += line.count(word)


    print (f"The word '{word}'' appears roughly {times} times in {book1}.")
```

I've written the code but I don't understand why I need the 'times' variable to make this work? I tried to delete it but it comes out saying 0 times.

Is there a more efficient way to do what I'm doing?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't have the variable `times`, where would you put the count?

Comment: Are you asking why you need the `for line in lines:` loop?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I wrote the code and I'm sure at the times I knew why I needed it but I can't recall. If it's just a variable to store the count, could I not just declare this as an empty list?

Comment: Declare what as an empty list?

Comment: Are you asking why `times = lines.count(word)` doesn't return the count that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `lines` is a list, `lines.count(word)` returns the number of lines that are exactly equal to `word`. This is `0` for two reasons:

1. The strings returned by `readlines()` all end in newline (except maybe the last line). Since `word` doesn't end with newline, it will never match any of them exactly.
2. Even if you remove the newlines, you're comparing a single word to an entire line. So unless the file contains one word per line, with a space after the word, the elements of `lines` will never exactly match `word`.

On the other hand, since `line` is a single string, `line.count(word)` counts the number of substrings of `line` that match `word`. The `for` loop adds up the number of substrings in all the lines of the file.

Note that if you did have a line containing just `"the "`, your code would count that word twice. There's no need to do

```
times = lines.count(word)
```

before the loop. You should just initialize `times = 0`.

You can also use the `sum()` function:

```
times = sum(line.count(word) for line in lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really simple way to just read in the entire file and count the occurrences:

```
book1 = 'imitation_of_christ.txt'
book2 = 'jesus_of_history.txt'

with open(book1, encoding='utf-8') as book1:
    book = book1.read()
    word = 'the '
    times = book.count(word)

    print (f"The word '{word}'' appears roughly {times} times in {book1}.")
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a much better way!